# How to display directory path if a drive is named "\"

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to create a script to pull files off of a handheld bar code scanner, however, the drive on the device is named "\" and my script can't find the proceeding folders. Here is my script.

```
@echo off
title Scan Backup
xcopy "Computer\PASCO\\\My Documents" "C:\Users\VHATAMGrecoM0\Documents\Scan Backup" /E /C /I /Q /G /H /R /K /Y /Z /J
@pause
```

Answer (score 0):

The >"Computer\PASCO\\My Documents"

Xcopy takes file paths.

`\\server\share\path\file` or `drive:\path\file`

Your drive is not called \ as it's illegal to call anything \.